# JavaFx: Pathing and Getting audio files to work in my .jar

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently making a small game in JavFx and am trying to play a sound when objects collide currently this is my implementation:

```
if (paddle.getBoundsInParent().intersects(circle.getBoundsInParent())) {
        dx *= -1;
        Media sound = new Media(getClass().getResource("/Audio/Paddle.m4a").toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

The audio files are stored in a source folder I made named "Audio" that is alongside the src and bin folders. My issue is that I cannot figure out the correct path for the audio files or how to extract them into a .jar using eclipse.

Comment: Put the files in a package and use the package names as the path relative to the class that you are calling the audio files with

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, hang on a minute

Comment: What is the package of the class that is using the audio files? i.e com.example.mypackage

Comment: Im just using a default package. Would this require me giving my class file a set package?

Comment: great so just put your files in the default package and just use the name of the file, meaning instead of `/Audio/Paddle.m4a` just use `Paddle.m4a`

Comment: Okay! Would that add them to the .jar when I extract it as well?

Comment: It would add them to the jar, but why are you extracting the jar?

Comment: Let me know if it works, as if it does I would like to post it as the answer

Comment: I'm extracting the class files to a jar as I want an executable to give to others.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and I am using eclipse to create the .jar, which also worked.

Comment: Great, please mark the answer as correct and upvote if i helped, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this would be to put your media files in the default package.

Then switch the file path in your code to just the name of the file, so `/audio/Paddle.mp4` becomes `Paddle.mp4`

Since you did not specify a path, java will look in the default package and find your media file.